# Eclipse can't refactor rename

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse Oxygen with Java. I can refactor some variables but since I updated to Java 9 it can no longer refactor some names like interface's methods, but it can refactor other kind of names or variables. It yields this internal error in the error log:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.base/java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem$1.read(JrtFileSystem.java:376)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.read(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.JrtFileSystem.getClassfileBytes(JRTUtil.java:330)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.JrtFileSystem.getClassfileContent(JRTUtil.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.JRTUtil.getClassfileContent(JRTUtil.java:153)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.AbstractClassFile.getClassFileContent(AbstractClassFile.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile.getJarBinaryTypeInfo(ClassFile.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile.getBinaryTypeInfo(ClassFile.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile.buildStructure(ClassFile.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:306)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getClassFileInfo(BinaryType.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getChildren(BinaryType.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getChildrenOfType(JavaElement.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getMethods(BinaryType.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.util.MethodOverrideTester.findOverriddenMethodInType(MethodOverrideTester.java:195)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2$2.visit(JavadocContentAccess2.java:837)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2$InheritDocVisitor.visitInheritDoc(JavadocContentAccess2.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2.findAttachedDocInHierarchy(JavadocContentAccess2.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2.getHTMLContent(JavadocContentAccess2.java:550)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:757)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.internalGetHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo2(JavadocHover.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:166)
```

It just renames but immediately undo the refactor operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug [525842](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525842).

The fix for this bug is currently scheduled to be in Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) due to be released on 11th April (2018).

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug in Eclipse. I have the same problem but I found a solution/workaround:

select the interface which contains the method you want to rename and press F4 to display 
the Type Hierarchy of the interface.

In the Type Hierarchy you will see in the bottom pane all the methods of your interface.
Select the one you want to rename, right click on it, and do the refactor-rename.
For me it renamed all the implementations of this method.